# One Selenium test script should support the website in different languages

Tags: java, selenium, localization, internationalization

I have a website for testing and also need to Automate the website tests using selenium with java using BDD framework.

The website is built in English language and it supports 52 different languages too. The only difference will be URL change and text language changes.

What is the best way to Automate this type of website?

The requirement is, website should be automated and my selenium script should support the website when in all the languages. Is this a possible scenario?

Thought i have in my mind is put the list of URL's and texts for assertions of a website for all the languages,(Which is a gigantic process) in a repository and automate all the tests. Then Webdriver startup function will have a logic to identify for which language i am running the website tests for? and execute the tests accordingly. But finding for a better way

Comment: yes, it is possible. now to get answer and start discussion, show us what you have thought, some prototype to provide feedback.  else move this answer to some freelancing website.

Comment: You can create a Languages.properties file or a .json file in which you can store the url for each of the localized site. What I have observed in the localisation automation testing is that only a part of the url changes and most of the url like the domain, query params etc. remain the same. You can also add localized text for each site for any static text verification

Comment: Thanks Sameer. I have a same thought. but this is a large process with respect to my website nature. wondering if there are any easy way for automating for a website that supports 50 different languages

Comment: When you say "Automate the website tests", which tests are you referring to?  You can build an automation framework that should require very little interaction with the text in the page, so it doesn't matter which language you are using.  But, if you're writing tests to verify actual text displayed, you have different requirements.  Which are you trying to do?

Comment: The tests will contain the text verification and also clicking on links, checkbox, Radio buttons. Also scrolling the page till bottom. these are the main tests.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things.

1. Make different property files for each language. Actually if your site is localized it's already there, you just need to re-use that.
2. if you are using Maven you can choose this property file based on the variable you pass in maven command. which would be easy to configure in jenkins as well.
3. Use property files only for text verification for finding element use unique IDs, if element doesn't have that ask developers to use it rather than making any xpath/css which contains text.